# Why I can't fetch an attribute inside object's __setattr__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading

I have a class with attributes that I could changed after check the others attributes, so I coded this class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print(self.x)  # doesn't work

        self.__dict__[name] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myObj = MyClass(1)

    myObj.x = 2
```

But I got this error

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'x'
```

If I don't have `print(self.x)` the attribute is rewrite but I need to check the other attributes for changing another one.

I tried `self.__dict__[name]` and getattr(self, name) but I got the same error.

Comment: I assume that the `self.x = x` in the `__init__` is running the `__setattr__`  method - since you are, after all, setting an attribute. And there is indeed no `x` property on the object at that point.

Comment: @RobinZigmond On point. That should be an answer

Comment: @DeepSpace fair point, but I only said "I assume" because I am not confident enough in my Python knowledge to be sure that this was what is happening. (Although I was about 90%) I will leave AnonCoward's answer without adding another as it says the same with more detail.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yep, I was 90% of the way there as well till I ran it to see the full error.  Sorry for stealing your thunder, I wrote the response before checking for checking for comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full error message is informative:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_code.py", line 11, in <module>
    myObj = MyClass(1)
  File "example_code.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.x = x
  File "example_code.py", line 6, in __setattr__
    print(self.x)  # doesn't work
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'x'
```

You're seeing an error on the initialization of `MyClass`, which in turn calls `self.x = x`, which in turn is calling into your custom `__setattr__` implementation to do the work.  At this point it's trying to print `x`, but this is before `x` assigned to the class, since you haven't done that work yet.

There are a few ways to work around this, the most direct is probably to verify your class actually has the attribute before you try to access it:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, 'x'):
            print(self.x)  # works now

        self.__dict__[name] = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myObj = MyClass(1)

    myObj.x = 2
```